# Copy files from recovery-mode via root terminal

Tags: backup, root, recovery-mode

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS was damaged during an upgrade and it can't be fixed. I need to save all my files in the disk in another disk.

When I log in as root during recovery mode, I see all my files there and I can read them without issue.

However when I connect a new disk (usb or hard disk) via USB this is not visible in the **media** folder, therefore I have no way to copy the files somewhere else, what should be done so that I can connect an external disk and copy all the contents that I need into the other disk?

Comment: did you mount the drive? I don't believe that recovery mode will automount

Comment: The linked question addresses your immediate issue, though I believe that you will have an easier time with either a live Ubuntu system that allows file system through the familiar graphical user interface or a [re-installation “without formatting `/home`, as well as without any old config files”](/q/56051/175814).

Comment: @ravery and others, this was the right tip. Once I mounted the disk I needed, I had to make the file system writable with `mount -o remount,rw /` as in recovery mode it is read-only, I am now in the process of copying over the documents and all seems to be going in the right direction, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following to mount an external in recovery mode:

1. Plugin the external HDD, then run `sudo fdisk -l` to know the partition information.
2. Create a mount point:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /mnt/usb
   ```
3. Now mount it at the location in step 2:

   ```
   sudo mount -t <file_type> /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usb -o umask=000
   ```
4. Now you should be able to move the files over.

**Note"**

- `/dev/sdb1` is imaginary yours could be `/dev/sdc1`
- `umask=000` makes it writable

Source:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1165891

Answer (score 0):

use a live installation cd boot it then copy all the contents from your bricked ubuntu system to pendrive easy